# HttpConnection with Proxy Server

Tags: java-me, proxy, httpconnection

I have Java ME Application that uses `HttpConnection` API, Here I am easily able to make connection with Proxyless server. But my Question is How can I Connect to any Live Server which uses Proxy Connection?. Do I need to specify Proxy IP & port into my Java ME Code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
HTTPConnection.setProxyServer("my.proxy.dom", 8008);
HTTPConnection.dontProxyFor("localhost");
HTTPConnection.dontProxyFor(".mycompany.com");
AuthorizationInfo.addBasicAuthorization("my.proxy.dom", 8008, realm, user, passwd);
...
HTTPConnection con = new HTTPConnection(...);
```

For more information on advance connection check http://www.innovation.ch/java/HTTPClient/advanced_info.html